# ObjectContext.Refresh()?

Tags: entity-framework, refresh, reload, dirty-data, objectstatemanager

How to update ALL the dirty entities from the data store, and reset their changed values to the original store value?

The method [ObjectContext.Refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503718.aspx) requires as a parameter the entities to be refreshed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following usually works:

```
Context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, _
    Context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries())
```

It sometimes causes problems with EntityRelations. look at my comment for further details.

Comment: This just saved me many lines of code walking the object graph myself.

Comment: There is a bug, please take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757872/undelete-an-entity-marked-as-entitystate-delete

Comment: Sometimes you'd like to update even the unchanged items, cuz you want to refresh them against the changes made in database by other clients.

Comment: @Shimmy `GetObjectStateEntries()` requires a parameter (e.g. Modified), and when I pass one in I get an exception that the entity is disconnected from the context. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

You can use this code:

```
public void RefreshAll()
{
     // Get all objects in statemanager with entityKey 
     // (context.Refresh will throw an exception otherwise) 
     var refreshableObjects = (from entry in context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
                                                 EntityState.Deleted 
                                               | EntityState.Modified 
                                               | EntityState.Unchanged)
                                      where entry.EntityKey != null
                                      select entry.Entity);

     context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, refreshableObjects);
}
```

I wrote a post on how to RefreshAll() and refresh the context in some other ways:

http://christianarg.wordpress.com/2013/06/13/entityframework-refreshall-loaded-entities-from-database/

Comment: This will throw an exception if you have added items. Add this before to fix: `var addedEntries = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added).ToList();
            addedEntries.ForEach(entry => entry.Delete());`

Comment: @AncientSyntax You are right about the exception. Actually if you think about is it doesn't make sense to try to refresh a just added entity. I've edited the response removing the EntityState.Added from the code. In your proposed solution you are actually deleting the just added entity, so nothing will be added.

Comment: Is this related to SQL Version, so it works when running on a 12.0 SQL server but 11.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset ALL the changes, you could set the `ObjectContext` to null and re-instantiate it.

I believe this will achieve what you want.

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: I guess you work with ASP.NET, so it's easy for you to say it, I use a long life-cycle context instance.

Answer (score 0):

We use this:

```
return Context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Deleted
System.Data.EntityState.Modified).All(ose 
  => {
    if(ose.Entity != null)
      Context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, ose.Entity);
      return true;
    });
```

Where "Context" is the context to refresh. We filter by change state and entities to avoid new entities and relations.