# Undelete an entity marked as EntityState.Delete?

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many, entity-relationship, navigation-properties

instead of talking let me talk with code:

```
Dim Contact = Context.Contacts.Include("Phones")
Dim phone = Contact.Phones(0)
Contact.Remove(phone)
```

How do I refresh the context now, canceling last relation deletion?

I tried:

```
Context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, phone) 'Doesn't recover the relation
Context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, _
    ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Deleted))
```

the last one throws an InvalidOperationException:
The element at index 0 in the collection of objects to refresh has a null EntityKey property value or is not attached to this ObjectStateManager.

**Important** *Table structure:*

*Contact*: FirstName, LastName
*Phone*: Number, Note
*ContactPhone* (many-to-many): ContactId (nav), PhoneId (nav)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I believe this is a bug, I reported it to Microsoft please vote and share your ideas: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=513174