# Workaround for Entity Framework Context.Refresh bug?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, objectcontext

I ran into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757872/undelete-an-entity-marked-as-entitystate-delete) problem using EF4 and a self-referential table (implementing an adjacency list hierarchy).
NOTE: *not* a many-to-many reference, just a one-to-many on a single table.
Attempts to resolve an intermittent `InvalidOperationException` ("*...The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state...*") using `Context.Refresh` fail due to an apparent bug in EF4.

I saw, from following Shimmy's connect.microsoft.com link, on the aforementioned post, that the bug is still outstanding.
Can anyone recommend a workaround?
What do you do if your database and Entity Framework get out of sync?

**EDIT**
Some more facts that may help:

1. When I get the `InvalidOperationException` and the message says *"The changes to the database were committed successfully..."*, it is not true. They weren't.
   I tried to change an object's `ParentId` from 1 to null (`ParentId` of type `int?`).
2. My object's `ParentId` attribute is correctly changed to the expected value (null). I call `Context.SaveChanges()`. Then, the exception is thrown. I check the DB, and the value has **not** been updated. In this case, `ParentId` is still 1 in the database.
3. Inside the `catch`, if I try to requery the object via
    `myObj = Context.MyObjects.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Id == id)`,
    the object's `ParentId` remains the same. It does not get updated by the (incorrect) database value!
   Now I think, *Okay, that seems weird, but maybe if I save again the db will be corrected.*
4. Calling a subsequent `Context.SaveChanges()` from inside the `catch` still does not update the database. (But this time, an exception is not thrown.)
5. If I make a new call to my SetParent method,
   `myObj = Context.MyObjects.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Id == id)`,
   correcly populates the object's `ParentId` parameter to 1, the value from the database.

Additionally, for giggles, I set the object's `ParentId` to it's own Id, instead of null, to denote parentlessness. This worked fine and did not cause the `InvalidOperationException`. But, it's a PITA for other reasons. E.g., the object reports having itself as an extra child.
So, the questions are:

- What is it about trying to set my self-referential `int? ParentId` to null that causes an exception?
- Why does the db not get updated before the exception?
- And why, inside the `catch`, can't I resync?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requery the object from the database through the context...

**EDIT** - in response to your update, if you submit changes for an object within a context, an an error happens, using the same context most likely is the problem.  Try recreating the context in the catch to requery and reupdate, and see if that works any better.

Comment: Brian, recreating the context in the catch seems to be the answer to the resync problem. Thank you. Still not sure why the problem is occurring in the first place, but at least now I can get on with my life. :)

Comment: The object context is a unit of work; it retains all of the changes it needs to sync to the database.  So in catch, it probably still is trying to push the erroring object up to the database.  Even though you requery, the OC will return the previously queried object if it stored in its internal state.